# Access secret value in KV from appsetting of .net core app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault, appsettings, azure-storage-account

I have deployed a .net core api application to send a message to queue by reading the connection string.
I have given key vault administrator and key vault contributor to the identity of the app service.
I placed the connection string in the appsettings.json and it worked.
I placed the value of connection string in key vault and used the uri of the key vault and made required code changes and that worked as well.

Now I am referring the secret value in appsettings like below:

```
"MyConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyConnectionString/)"
```

And when I call the api I get 500 and when I saw logs from app service I see the below error:

```
Exception: 
System.FormatException: No valid combination of account information found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;Parse&gt;b__97_0(String err)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseImpl(String connectionString, CloudStorageAccount&amp; accountInformation, Action`1 error)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString)
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyConnectionString/)"
  //"VaultName": "https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/"
}
```

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    public interface IMessageSender
    {
        Task Send(string content);
    }

    public class AzureQueueSender : IMessageSender
    {
        public AzureQueueSender(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;                
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public async Task Send(string content)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyConnectionString");
            await SendMessage(connectionString);
        }

        private static async Task SendMessage(string connectionString)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queuename");
            var message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello World!");
            await queue.AddMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code and configuration file?

Comment: I have shared app setting above the rest is as is you get with a new project. From code, please let me know what exactly do you need?

Comment: Added the code which I think should be enough, let me know if you need anything specific? No changes in program/start up apart from injecting IMessageSender in startup. There is a controller that has a post method which calls Send method.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the connection string to console to prove that the code is actually picking it up or not? If yes, I think the issue is not with the code but with the connection string itself because it looks like you are not able to extract the storage account name from the connection string. Make sure that you are using the connection string and not the access key instead.

Comment: I'm not very sure which tutorial you followed to get key vault secret. According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0), it provides [a sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/key-vault-configuration/samples/6.x/KeyVaultConfigurationSample/Program.cs#L39) which using `builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault` to get azure key vault configurations.

Comment: @AnupamChand This code would not execute in local so I am not sure how to get this printed in console

Comment: @TimyWang I did try this approach and it works however I need to try one thing in this approach which is to ensure not all secrets are getting loaded as the key vault I am using is not only specific for one application. If you have tried this do let me know

Comment: However I would prefer the way I am trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli as this does not require a code change and I can work with hard coding the connection string/secrets in my local/dev and use reference for higher environments

Comment: The connection string I took is from Storage Account -> Access Keys -> Connection String. I used the same when I tried hard coded, and then using AddAzureKeyVault (had the same value in KV secret). The value of my secret is DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dummystorageacountname;AccountKey=dummykeywithlotsofcharsnumsymbols==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Comment: Add the key with `MyConnectionString` and value `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyConnectionString/)` in the App Service Configuration => Application Settings and check.

Comment: @Harshitha Thanks a lot! This seems to be working, please post this as answer while I do some checks so I can accept it

Comment: Sure will explain in detail and post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access and retrieve the Key Vault Secret value using the reference, we need to set the App setting in the deployed Azure App Service.

The Key name must be same as the key which you have set in the local `appsettings.json` file.

- As you have set the key with name  `MyConnectionString` , Iam setting the same `key-value` in the Configuration section of the deployed app in portal.

`Azure App` => `Configuration` => `Application Setting` = >`New App Setting`

[image]

> ```cs
> Name : MyConnectionString
> Value:"@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyConnectionString/)"
> ```

- The App setting which you have set is now available in the  Environment Variable (KUDU Console) with key `APPSETTING_MyConnectionString`.

[image]

Even we can retrieve the value as

```
var myconn= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_MyConnectionString");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Harshitha! Just want to add it worked for me post removing this entry from appsettings json file and also I removed the roles I gave the identity as well. The preferred way if role is required would be to use access policies in KV like I have stated in my question as well.